# How to use RxJava with Android Room Library?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am developing in `Adnroid` `RxJava` with `Room`.

I use retrofit to call API and update the value in database like the following code:

```
    override fun certifyMail(userInfo: Userinfo): Observable<Int> {
        return securityApi.certifyUserInfo(userInfo)
            .map {
            //return Observable<Status> here
                when(it.status){
                    "OK" -> {
                        it
                    }
                    else -> {
                        throw Exception(it.msg!!)
                    }
                }
            }
            .flatMap {
                userInfoDataSource.updateUserCertifyMailInfo(userInfo.account,1)
            //How to convert the return type to Observable<Int> from Int.
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
```

When the response is `OK` from API, I will update the value in database like the following.

```
@Query("UPDATE certify_info SET value = :value  WHERE account = :account")
fun updateCertifyMailConfirm(account:String,value: Int):Int
```

But the return type of database is `Int`.
How to covert it to `Observable<Int>` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Room library can return RxJava's types.

Add `implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.0-rc01"` library to your project

Checkout this [great article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) for better understanding.

Also checkout [Google official sample about this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample)

And simply edit your `updateUserCertifyMailInfo` method  in one of this ways (choose one that suits more):

**With Maybe:**

```
@Query("UPDATE certify_info SET value = :value  WHERE account = :account")
fun updateCertifyMailConfirm(account:String,value: Int):Maybe<Int>
```

**With Single:**

```
@Query("UPDATE certify_info SET value = :value  WHERE account = :account")
fun updateCertifyMailConfirm(account:String,value: Int):Single<Int>
```

**With Flowable/Observable:**

```
@Query("UPDATE certify_info SET value = :value  WHERE account = :account")
fun updateCertifyMailConfirm(account:String,value: Int):Flowable<Int>
```

**Important!** Read carefully about how every type behaves with Room Queries